# How to change an activitiy's strings with clicked TextView

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

I have two activities, `MainActivity` and `SecondActivity`. In `MainActivity` I have 10 `TextViews` listed. And all of them clickable. I want to go to `SecondActivity` when any of these `TextViews` are clicked and second `Activity` shows text about clicked `TextView`.

For example:

`MainActivity` textViews:

1) Mercedes
2) BMW
3) Audi
4) Porsche

When Mercedes clicked, in `SecondActivity` a text about mercedes and on `SecondActivity` a back button. When BMW clicked on `MainActivity` `SecondActivity` open again but text about BMW.

I hope I could explain.

Comment: Can't you pass it using intent?

Comment: You must past data using bundles/intents to anothers activities

Comment: You want to implement clicklistener and pass the data in bundle or using putExtra function

Comment: I think "context" is not the correct word. the context is the Activity itself. you need the name of the brand on the button. right?

Comment: for my design, textView looks better so i used Clickable TextvViews; but they work like button! When any of these clicked, in second activity i would like to show information about clicked car.

Comment: Ok, so change "context" word because it can cause wrong answers

Comment: Why aint you using list instead of so many text views? Why aint you passing the data as intent? Why aint you using fragment for this light weight operation?  What exactly will you do just by printing the text of the textview, I am pretty sure you want to to do something else. Can you update the question with the exact task you want to do?

Comment: Dear Mohammad Atif, because for now i dont know exactly how to use fragments or other things, i am beginner :)

Comment: so two things for you: for the goal you are aiming for check my answer, I told you all steps 0 to complete solution, second have a look at some tutorials, I always suggest the "The new boston" channel on youtube because they have a perfect guide for beginners ;)

Comment: I will do it immediatelly! Thank you Pier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmw);
    textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent (this,SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("data","BMW");

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

     //similarly send data to next activity
  }
}
```

SecondActivity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("data");

    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    textView.setText(message);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass data from `Activity A` to `Activity B` using `bundle` and `intent`

**To send data from Activity A**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Datas", brandString);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

**To get data from Activity B**

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

if (bundle != null) {
    String data = bundle.getString("Datas");
    StringBrand = data;
    StringBrand = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Datas");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two steps:

for each of your textView, add an `onClickListener`.

**You can even do it on XML side:**

```
<TextView
  ...
  android:onClick="onClick"
  android:clickable="true"
/>
```

*You can even do it by setting an `onClickListener` on each TextView by java side*

**On Java code do the following:**

```
private void onClick(View v){
  String clickedText = ((TextView)v).text);
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
  intent.putExtra("key", clickedText);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

**now on ActivityB code you do the following in onCreate**

```
Intent retrieved = getIntent();
String chosenWord = retrieved.getStringExtra("key");
if(chosenword != null){
  switch(chosenWord){
    case "BMW":
      myTextView.text = "BMW detail text";
      break;
    ...
  }
}
```

Hope this helps